# I have a string like this "15.May-2019" and I want to replace May with 05

Tags: c#

(so it looks like this "15.05-2019")but I don't want to remove the dot or the dash.How do I do this in C#

Comment: Look into how to use DateTime in C#

Comment: What does “like this” mean? Is it always “.May-” or could it be “.January-” or “-jan-” or something else?

Comment: I'm not c# developer but here you go: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/c-sharp-replace-method/amp/

Answer (score 2):

You could parse it to a `DateTime` and then format it back.

```
var result = DateTime.ParseExact("15.May-2019", "dd.MMMM-yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
    .ToString("dd.MM-yyyy");
```

This is useful if you need to handle dates with any month in them.

Note that the `MMMM` will work for long month names, but if you're dealing with short names `MMM` would be the way to go (for May the short and long names are the same).  You can also use the overload of `ParseExact` that takes multiple formats if you need to handle both.

Answer (score 1):

```
var str = "15.May-2019"; 
str = str.Replace("May", "05")
```

Comment: You should assign the result of the call to `Replace` to something because it does not mutate the string you call it on.

Comment: @juharr `.Replace` returns string and strings are immutable :) i know. I assume it is obvious

Comment: Never assume, it's a common error that beginners make and ti's best to make it explicit that you need to assign the value to get the result

Comment: @juharr ok, edited answer

Answer (score 0):

To replace part of a string you can do:

```
var date = "15.05-2019";
date = date.Replace("05", "May");

Console.WriteLine(date); 

output : "15.May-2019"
```

Comment: Your values are backwards.  They want to replace "May" with "05"